# Python (pySerial): cannot trim/remove CR, LF or unexpected characters from string

Tags: python, string, pyserial

I am using an Arduino to output Temp & Hum data from a sensor, this is being read by a PC running Python using pySerial.  The data is reading in correctly but I would like to remove the CR/LF and unexpected characters.  One idea I found on this site was to use lstrip or lreplace but they do not seem to work correctly.  They will remove one instance of the character but even repeating the line or making a small loop has no effect.

This is what the program Prints (Bottom line is string after I've tried to cut out the unnecessary characters):

> [b'\n', b'\r\n', b'Read sensor: OK\r\n', b'Hum40.00\r\n', b'TempC18.00\r\n']
>
> [" b'Hum40.00\r\n'", " b'TempC18.00\r\n']"]

I am aiming for it to read:

> [Hum40.00, TempC18.00]

I can hopefully fine tune the message later.

This is the code:

```
    import serial as ser
    import time

    count = 0
    msgArray = []
    saveMsg = []

    ser = ser.Serial('COM16', 9600, timeout=1, parity='N', stopbits=1,                                bytesize=8, xonxoff=0) # Setting up and opening COM port
    ser.close()
    ser.open()

    def readSerial():               #reads a whole line from COM port
        serLine = ser.readline()
        return serLine

    def sveMsgCut():                #saves the buffer as a message then cuts message
        cutMsg = saveMsg
        words = cutMsg.split(',')
        return words

    while True:                     #main program
        dataSerial = readSerial()

        if count < 5:                       #reads COM port 5 times and passes along to buffer msgArray
            msgArray.append(dataSerial)
            count = count+1
        else:
            print(msgArray)                     #~display msgArray
            saveMsg = str(msgArray)             #convert to string
            splitMsg = saveMsg.split(',')       #splits string (csv)
            phrase = splitMsg[3:5]              #cuts out excess either side of Temp & Hum/
            phraseString = str(phrase)
            phraseNew = phraseString.lstrip("/n") #an attempts ot remove CR

            print(phraseNew)                    #~print adjusted string

            saveMsg = msgArray
            count = 0       #resets msgArray and counter
            msgArray = []



            time.sleep(5)
```

I am fairly new to programming, especially Python so it may be something simple that I've missed but have tried several different ideas and cannot remove the extra characters.

Comment: This is 6 years old but it might help someone to note that the parameter to `lstrip`  should be `"\n"` and not `"/n"` and perhaps `strip` would generally be more useful...

Answer (score 1):

not sure why rstrip/lstrip do not work for you.

this code runs as expected on my machine:

```
s = '\r\nHum40.00\r\n'
print (s.rstrip().lstrip())
```

The only difference I see is the "/n" parameter so instead try:

```
phraseNew = phraseString.lstrip()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback.  I tried your first example through CMD and can see that it works, but it still has no effect in the program.  I am dealing with one element from the list to simplify things now, and try and get the humidity reading cleared up.

Comment: what environment do you use? It might be an IDE issue.

Comment: I'm using PyCharm on Windows.  Anaconda is installed as well.  I tried running the program through the CMD prompt as well, I think it gave the same response though I will have to check.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to go about this another way.  Placed the raw serial data into a list and extracted the temp and humidity readings then joined them together as a string:

```
else:
        print(msgArray)                        #Raw serial data
        msgString = str(msgArray)              #convert serial data to str
        character = list(msgString)            #str to list 

# the next two lines extract the temp & hum readings then converts 
  them to their respective strings

        humidity = ''.join(character[46:51])      
        temperature = ''.join(character[65:70])

print('H:' + (humidity) + ' T:' + (temperature))
```

The output now looks like this (Raw then processed data):

> [b'\n', b'\r\n', b'Read sensor: OK\r\n', b'Hum40.00\r\n', b'TempC21.00\r\n']
>
> H:40.00 T:21.00

Now onto the next stage.

Answer (score 0):

One thought:

So what you have now is:

```
"b'Hum40.00\r\n'"
```

Now what I see here is that the ' symbol is now a part of the string. This means that ' is the last symbol instead of \r\n. I have found success with starting on the outside are working inwards. Let's first start by removing the b. To do this try:

```
x = str(ser.readline())
x = x.lstrip("b")
```

Now we should see this:

```
"'Hum40.00\r\n'"
```

Next remove the '

```
x = x.strip("'")
```

Now we see this:

```
"Hum40.00\r\n"
```

Now the tricky part here is deleting the \r\n. There is a post here:[Can't delete "\r\n" from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383938/cant-delete-r-n-from-a-string)
that explains why:

```
x = x.rstrip("\r\n")
```

will not work.

Instead type:

```
x = x.rstrip("\\r\\n")
```

Final code:

```
x = str(ser.readline())
x = x.lstrip("b")
x = x.strip("'")
x = x.rstrip("\\r\\n")
print(x)
```

Should yeild:

```
"Hum40.00"
```