# Can't delete "\r\n" from a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace, strip

I have a string like this:

```
la lala 135 1039 921\r\n
```

And I can't remove the `\r\n`.

Initially this string was a bytes object but then I converted it to string

I tried with `.strip("\r\n")` and with `.replace("\r\n", "")` but nothing...

Comment: You need `.strip()`

Comment: In your example, is `\r` a literal backslash and an 'r'?  If so, then you need to change your call to be `.strip("\\r\\n")` or `.replace("\\r\\n", "")`.

Comment: @ChristianDean So it would seem! What jszakmeister posted is correct then.

Comment: @jszakmeister it works, thanks! if you write an answer I'll accept it!

Comment: You could also just slice off the end like `my_string[0:-5]`. Or use `re.sub(r'\\r\\n', '', mystr)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that the string contains a literal backslash followed by a character.  Normally, when written into a string such as `.strip("\r\n")` these are interpreted as escape sequences, with `"\r"` representing a carriage return (0x0D in the ASCII table) and `"\n"` representing a line feed (0x0A).

Because Python interprets a backslash as the beginning of an escape sequence, you need to follow it by another backslash to signify that you mean a literal backslash.  Therefore, the calls need to be `.strip("\\r\\n")` and `.replace("\\r\\n", "")`.

Note: you really don't want to use `.strip()` here as it affects a lot more than just the end of the string as it will remove backslashes and the letters "r" and "n" from the string. `.replace()` is a little better here in that it will match the whole string and replace it, but it will match `\r\n` in the middle of the string too, not just the end.  The most straight-forward way to remove the sequence is the conditional given below.

You can see the list of escape sequences Python supports in the [String and Byte Literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) subsection of the Lexical Analysis section in the Python Language Reference.

For what it's worth, I would not use `.strip()` to remove the sequence.  [`.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) removes all characters in the string (it treats the string as a set, rather than a pattern match).  `.replace()` would be a better choice, or simply using slice notation to remove the trailing `"\\r\\n"` off the string when you detect it's present:

```
if s.endswith("\\r\\n"):
    s = s[:-4]
```

Comment: Your strip solution is dangerous, for example `"return\\r\\n".strip("\\r\\n")` becomes just `"etu"`.

Comment: It wasn't meant to be a solution of how to remove the characters, it was meant to show why the OP's solution wasn't working.  But you're right, `.strip()` is inappropriate here.

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> my_string = "la lala 135 1039 921\r\n"
>>> my_string.rstrip()
'la lala 135 1039 921'
```

Alternate solution with just slicing off the end, which works better with the bytes->string situation:

```
>>> my_string = b"la lala 135 1039 921\r\n"
>>> my_string = my_string.decode("utf-8")
>>> my_string = my_string[0:-2]
>>> my_string
'la lala 135 1039 921'
```

Or hell, even a regex solution, which works better:

```
re.sub(r'\r\n', '', my_string)
```

Comment: @AllExJ How strange. is the `\r\n` not at the end of the string?

Comment: it is at the end

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. if I do `str(b'la lala 135 1039 921\r\n').replace("\\r\\n", "")` it works. I'll leave the answer, though, just in case someone googles it and sees it.

Comment: @AllExJ You're welcome, but read my updated answer. I've provided solutions that should work for you.

Comment: Just an FYI: `my_string[0:-5]` should be `my_string[0:-4]`.  Actually, the way the it's interpreted (as an escape sequence), it would be `my_string[0:-2]`.  It would trim off too much otherwise.

Comment: @StefanPochmann `In [13]: str(b"la lala 135\r\n 1039 921\r\n")[0:-5]
Out[13]: "b'la lala 135\\r\\n 1039 921"` Forgive the formatting. Also @jszakmeister I *did* test it before posting it.

Comment: @StefanPochmann yea, you're right. I just typed it out that way for clarity, I should have just copy/pasted it from the terminal.

Comment: Using `str()` on a bytes object yields it's repr(), which is probably not what you want.  You need to use `.decode()`: `b"la lala 135 1039 921\r\n".decode("ascii")[0:-2]`.

Comment: OK, everything should be accurate now.

Comment: @CoryMadden I hear ya, it's just not doing what you might think.  The actual result from your operations is `"b'la lala 135 1039 921"`.  Notice the leading `b'`, that's because it repr()'d the string and didn't really convert it.  You can see that in the output you pasted into the comment too.  I didn't mean any offense, just wanted you to realize what was happening. :-)

Comment: @jszakmeister yea, I saw that when I was performing it, but it's been a long day so I was just like "oh yea, just slice off the extra apostrophe, too and..." And no offense taken, of course.

Comment: No worries @CoryMadden.  I hope tomorrow is a better day for you. :-)

Comment: regex solution worked for me after the others failed

Answer (score 3):

'\r\n' is also a standard line delimiter for .splitlines(), so this can also work.

```
>>> s = "la lala 135 1039 921\r\n"
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>
>>> t = ''.join(s.splitlines())
>>> t
'la lala 135 1039 921'
>>> type(t)
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also determine the length of the string say 20 characters then truncate it to 18 regardless of the last two characters or verify they are the characters before you do that.  Sometimes it helps to compare the ascii value first pseudo logic:

if last character in string is tab, cr, lf or ? then shorten the string by one.  Repeat till you no longer find ending characters matching tab, cr, lef, etc.

Answer (score -1):

test2 = test.replace('\r\n', "") will do the fun

Comment: The OP already tried that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).